# How can I use two WiFi routers with one cable to the ISP router?

Tags: router, ethernet, networking, isp

Let me explain...

There is the fiber optic ISP router on the first floor, connected to it via LAN cable is a switch, connected to the switch via LAN cable is a WiFi router on the 7th.

I want to add another WiFi router on the 7th floor without having to get another LAN cable to connect that new router to the switch or the ISP router.

Is there a way I can "share" that one cable between the two WiFi routers? This is what I'm thinking of...

[image]

Comment: Put in a switch and use a trunk between the switches.

Comment: If this is about home networking, the question is off-topic here, see the [help]. You might want to try on [su].

Answer (score 2):

The cable can only be used between two devices, one on each end. The "adapter" you want is a switch on the upper floor, and you create a trunk between the two switches to separate the traffic from the different SSID, or you could have the same SSID with no trunk, but you would need to do something else to facilitate roaming (we do not have enough information about your network to explain that further).

---

I think you really mean that you hasve WAPs on the upper floor, not routers.